# Unable to cast object of type...

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering what's wrong with the following codes I got below. I'm creating a form where a user can change their password but I always get an error whenever I try to run my system. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
Public Class Form7

Dim cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database1.accdb"
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using dbCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select count ([Password]) from students where [Password] like ?", cnString)
            dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textbox1.Text)
            Dim result As Integer = DirectCast(dbCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
            If result = 1 Then
                Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE students SET StudFacID = @STUDID, [Password] = @Password" & _
                             "WHERE ID = StudFacID"

                ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
                ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

                Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
                    Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, cnString)

                        cnString.Open()
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDID", TxtID.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text)
                    End Using

                End Using
            End If

                End Using 

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

[image: This is a screenshot of the error I get]

Comment: `OleDbCommand` constructor takes a `OleDbConnection` object not a connection string.  Use the conn string to create the connection object.  [This may be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452)

Comment: Don't be a novice! Set Option Strict **on**. Read the section *"To set Option Strict in the IDE"* here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to construct an `OldDbCommand` object:

```
New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("your sql command", cnString)
```

using [the constructor that takes two arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yeecx59.aspx).  That constructor expects a `String` and a `OleDbConnection`, but instead you're giving it a `String` and a `String`.  As the error says, a `String` can't be cast to an `OldDbConnection`, so this attempt fails.

Create [an `OleDbConnection` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) to use with your command object.  Perhaps something like this:

```
Using dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
    Using dbCommand As New OleDbCommand("your sql command", dbConnection)
        ' the rest of your code
    End Using
End Using
```

(Basically, you should be doing the exact same thing you're already doing with the `conn` and `cmd` objects.)

---

Also, as a side note, and this is **very important**... You should ***not*** be storing user passwords as ***plain text***.  User passwords should be hashed and should *never* be recoverable.  What you're currently doing is *grossly irresponsible* to your users.