# I can't insert a new record into Ms.Access 2007

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, database-connection

I am new to visual basic . 
I am writing to insert a new record into my ms access database by visual basic 2010. Here is my code.

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form9

```
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
    'Change the following to your access database location
    dataFile = "C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "insert into Table2 ([P_Name], [Age], [Phone], [Train_Name], [Seat_No], [Berth]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("P_Name", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Phone", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Train_Name", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Seat_No", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Berth", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()

        MsgBox("Your Ticket was booked successfully ! ")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

When I executed this code . It gave me an error in    myConnection.Open() . It said that .Open() is not a valid name . Please help me !

Comment: I have had a similar error before. And I have found it useful to open the other Access database first

    dim accessApp
    set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
    accessApp.visible = False
    accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\path.accdb")
accessApp.Run "myLinker"

Comment: Do Not try to reuse the same connection object over and over.  That is not how they are meant to be used.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28213871/1070452)