# 'Data criteria mismatch SQL' when using Dates

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to use this query, but I get an error

> Data mismatch in criteria

`Dat` is the `Date` column inside the MS Access database. I'm trying to select the sum of column named `Total` for every row named `Pro` between a date picked from the datepickers...

There are many posts regarding this, but my query is different then those

```vb
Dim DTST As String
DTST = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString

Dim DTEn As String
DTEn = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString

Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro =@Pro AND Dat BETWEEN'" + DTST + "' AND '" + DTEn + "'"

Dim cmd2 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query1, dbCon)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro", ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Comment: Hey date/time format expert! Why don't you use sql parameter for `DTST` and `DTEn` and let the framework do it's job? Did you ever wonder what `<DateTime>.ToString()` returns? Is it a valid ms-access date format? What about localization?

Comment: It is a valid format. I've changed it to match the format in my database. Tried it without ToString, same circle of errors, either syntax error, or data mismatch :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My edit seems to be cancelled, so here is:

```
Dim DTST As String
DTST = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'#'")

Dim DTEn As String
DTEn = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'#'")

Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro =@Pro AND Dat BETWEEN " + DTST + " AND " + DTEn + ""
```

Answer (score 4):

The Dates are just additional parameters.  One of the problems with the way you (and the other answers) are doing it is that you are converting perfectly good `DateTime` variables to string.  MSAccess/OleDb will usually make sense of things, but it is unnecessary and allowing something else to interpret your intent is usually undesirable.

The DB columns must be implemented as a `Date` type in order for the data to be treated as `Dates` (BETWEEN), but you do not need to "format" the Date variables (ever).

Another problem is disposing of Command and Connection objects when done with them:

```vb
Dim SQL = "SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro =@Pro AND Dat BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2"


Using dbCon As OleDbCOnnection(GetConnection()),
     cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbCon)

    dbCon.Open

    ' ToDO be sure SelectedItems.COunt >0 earlier
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro", ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem.ToString)
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1",  DateTimePicker1.Value)   
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2",  DateTimePicker2.Value)  

    Dim Total = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    ...
End Using     ' close and dispose of Command and Connection objects
```

As you can see, you pass DateTime values to it as any other parameter, and the DTP's`.Value` property will work perfectly well without any massaging or processing.

Here is a link for info on the [`GetConnection()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452) and dbConnections in general.

---

Note that `OleDB` does not actually use named parameters (@Pro, @dt1).  They are just *placeholders*, you have to `AddWithValue` in the same order as they appear in the SQL statement.  It is more common to see params specified as "?", but meaningful params are helpful in mapping the right var to the right param in code.

Finally, it cant happen with a `DateTimePicker`, but gluing bits of string from UI controls together to make SQL can result in SQL injection attacks and should always be avoided.  SQL using parameters is generally easier to code, build, read and mantain.

Answer (score 1):

A parameterised date in Access needs to be wrapped in # outside the quotes (and inside if it was a literal date e.g. #10/10/2015#

```
Dim DTST As String
DTST = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'#'")

Dim DTEn As String
DTEn = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'#'")

Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro =@Pro AND Dat BETWEEN " + DTST + " AND " + DTEn + ""

Dim cmd2 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query1, dbCon)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro", ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

Comment: I have tried with "#" before and got syntax error...  `Additional information: Syntax error in date in query expression 'Pro =@Pro AND Dat BETWEEN #'4/1/2015 12:00:00 AM'# AND #'4/2/2015 12:00:00 AM''.`

Comment: Try it now, ive changed the position

Comment: Now it says `Data type mismatch` again :S These errors have been circling no matter what I try...

Comment: Try again with them directly on the values

Comment: This one gives "expression expected" on the first "#" and makes the query invalid :S Thanks for sticking with this so far...

Comment: You need properly formatted string expression for the date values - as edited.