# .NET - Importing class with connection to database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, class, connection

I want to import a class to another class so that I don't have to write the same code X times.

I have a file with the connection to the database called **connectDB.vb**.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Namespace connectDB1
    Public Class connectDB
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; UserId=root; 
                                Password=root; Database=something")

        Public Sub doConnection()
            Try
                connection.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error")
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And I want to import **connectDB.vb** to **File1.vb**

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MyApp.connectDB1

Public Class File1

    Dim connectDataBase As New connectDB
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; UserId=root; Password=root; Database=something")

    Private Sub File1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'doConnection()
        connectDataBase.doConnexion()
    End Sub

    'Private Sub doConnection()
    '    Try
    '        connection.Open()
    '    Catch ex As Exception
    '        MsgBox("Error")
    '    End Try
    'End Sub

    Private Sub addProduct()
        Dim dbcomm As MySqlCommand
        Dim dbread As MySqlDataReader

        If txtBoxQuantity.Text <> "" And txtBoxPrice.Text <> "" And txtBoxProduct.Text <> "" Then
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand("insert into products (price, stock, name) values(@price, @stock, @name)", connection)
            dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtBoxPrice.Text())
            dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", txtBoxQuantity.Text())
            dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtBoxProduct.Text())
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader() ' GIVES ERROR
            dbread.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles agregarProducto.Click
        addProduct()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But when I run this code that it's suposed to save the data in the DB it gives me this error:

*InvalidOperationException was unhandled. Connection must be valid and open.*

connectDB.vb connects to the database since I debugged and it connects to the DB, but when I want to do some sql sentence in the File1.vb it gives that error.

Without trying to import the class the code works, but I'm just trying to improve my code, as you can see the commented code is the code I used to connect to the database.

Comment: You have issues with `Scope` - creating or opening a connection in that class does not connect your entire app to the DB.  Connections ought to be created as needed, then closed and disposed of.

Comment: @Plutonix so how shoud I do what I want?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452

Comment: @Plutonix, so what I have to do is replace the Mysql code you posted in that link in the connectDB.vb and in the File1.vb call the GetConnection function?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
Public Sub New()
  connectDataBase = New connectDB()
  connection = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; UserId=root; Password=root; Database=something")
End Sub
```