# Auto update access tables Cells with random numbers from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I searched many forums but didn't find any solution. I want to update access table cells from Vb.net. My table has fields:

```
[PanelNumber],[Date], [PVValue]
```

In Panel number field, there is some text like "Panel 1", "Panel 2" etc..
from vb, i will select that "Panel 1" after clicking a button, i need to fill that "PVValue" field with random numbers in given range, plz check my code below, when i try with this code, i am always getting same number in all rows
but need separate number (may be repeated in some rows)
LogTable2 is my table name

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=LoggedData.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=GodavarthiSuresh;"
        myNewConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myNewConnection.Open()

        Dim UpdateString As String = "update LogTable2 set [pvvalue]= @rndVal1 where panelnumber='" & panelnametxt.Text & "'"
        Dim UpdateCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(UpdateString, myNewConnection)
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Clear()
        Randomize()
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rndVal1", GetRandom())

        Try
            UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            UpdateCmd.Dispose()
            myNewConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Sub
' this is the function to get random number in given range
 Public Function GetRandom() As Integer
        Static Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Return Generator.Next(825, 850)
    End Function
```

Comment: What about passing the call for Randomize() into the function? I am not sure that it will do the trick, but the code will at least look clearer.

Comment: @Philippe Grondier  , i also tried using Randomize() in that GetRandom function, but still getting same random number for all rows, Please advice some other..

Comment: In your main proc, add a variable that will hold the random value, and display it before calling the AddWithValue method. You can then control if the problem comes from the GetRandom function (which I doubt) or the call to AddWithValue method.

Comment: No, that GetRandom function is working well, i tried it with adding 2 fields in that form, then it is working well, Problem is in Update command only. suppose there are 5 rows in that table with that condition, then that update command will be called 5 times, may be this solve :(

Comment: can you display the query string that is sent to the Db?

Comment: "update LogTable2 set [pvvalue]= @rndVal1 where panelnumber='" & panelnametxt.Text & "'"   This is the query string, it will update field pvvalue where panelnumber is taken from txt field

Comment: If your query updates multiple rows, they will all get the same random number because it *is* one query affecting multiple rows.  If you want each row to have a different random value, you need to loop and update them one at a time.  Also, `Randomize` does nothing here, and `panelnumber` should also be a query parameter

Comment: @Plutonix  Yes, i think so, Please advice loop, how to get count ?

Comment: If the answer solves your problem please click the checkmark next to the question.  That will remove it from the unanswered list and help others find solutions which work.  It also show that you participate in the process here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple rows for each panel and you want them to have different values, you need to update them individually.  Its is not true that update command will be "called" 5 times if there are five rows associated.  It will be executed once per click event.

To do what it sounds like you want, you need a unique identifier for each such as an `AutoIncrement` `ID` column.

```
Private RNG As New Random()
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(etc...

    Dim sql = "SELECT ID FROM LogTable2 WHERE panelnumber = @pnl"
    Dim pnlList As New List(Of Int32)

    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetACEConnection()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

            con.Open()

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnl", panelnametxt.Text)

            ' get affected row IDs into a list;
            Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While rdr.Read
                    pnlList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Item("ID")))
                End While
            End Using           ' close, dispose of reader
        End Using               ' dispose of cmd

        ' not sure you need a new command object
        sql = "UPDATE LogTable2 SET pvvalue = @rVal WHERE ID = @id"

        Using pcmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            ' loop thru ID list and update each row with
            ' new random value 825-849 inclusive
            For n As Int32 = 0 To pnlList.Count - 1
                pcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rVal", RNG.Next(825, 850))
                pcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pnlList(n))
                pcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ' clear for next iteration
                pcmd.Parameters.Clear()

            Next
        End Using                  ' close and dispose of pcmd
    End Using                      ' close and dispose of connection

End Sub
```

I dont like scattering the connection string in every method which opens a connection, so [a method for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452) is nice to have.

Notes:

- This depends on a unique `ID` column which is AutoIncrement (PK).  If you have some other unique identifier, use it but you have to have some way to identify rows individually.
- Rather  than a method to create a random value, since it is just one line, it might be easier to just use your RNG directly as shown.
- I cant test the code, but it should be close.
- Use `Using` blocks to close and dispose of DBObjects like connections, command and reader otherwise you can run out of resources.
- You can also initialize `Command` objects with the SQL and COnnection when you declare it rather than setting them as properties.  It makes the code a little more compact and less likely that you forget them.
- `Randomize` does nothing - it is meant to be used with the old VB6 `Rnd()`. You only need to [Escape] keywords in SQL, not every column name and `pvvalue` is not a keyword.
- A `DataTable` instead of a `Reader` could be used to get the rows but I am not sure it is any simpler.
- Finally, elements of a SQL WHERE clause can also be parameterized; there is no need to concat them just because it is a where rather than a column value.

Comment: Thank you so much , Working perfect

Comment: Ok, got it, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in database level,add auto increment value to database field

Comment: Yes, but i don't need auto increment, i need random numbers only

Comment: already tried so much of examples like that, but still updating with same random number in all rows