# Executing two cmd.commandtext in one line

Tags: vb.net, cmd

The program executes one cmd.commandtext at a time.  Both of my tables are using the same primary keys which is ID.

How do I execute both cmd.commandtext at the same time?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
Dim connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data    Source=C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Database1.accdb;"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = connection
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReal.Click
    If txtName.Text <> "" And txtId.Text <> "" And txtReceipt.Text <> "" Then

        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE customer Set Stu_Name = '" & txtName.Text & " '   " & "WHERE ID = " & txtId.Text & " ;  "

        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE admin Set receipt = '" & txtReceipt.Text & " '   " & "WHERE ID = " & txtId.Text & " ;  "

        cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmdUpdate.Dispose()

        MsgBox(txtName.Text + "Record Updated!")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your database? What is the ADO.NET client classes in use here? (SqlCommand, OleDbCommand, MySqlCommand...)

Comment: Hopefully there will be no students named "O'Brian" or "D'Angelo"

Comment: Practicaly it cannot happen because of db object locks. Unless you configure your db transaction in some sort of 'chaotic' isolation level.

Comment: see also [Reuse or Dispose DB Connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452)

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to say here is: Do not use string concatenation to build sql queries, but use always a parameterized query. Without it you will find a lot of problem like parsing of single quotes in your name or worst an Sql Injection hack. Said that, I suppose that you are using OleDb (probably with an Access database). This scenario doesn't support the execution of multiple command in a single sql statement.
You are forced to call the ExecuteNonQuery two times after changing the command text

```
Private Sub btnReal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReal.Click
    If txtName.Text <> "" And txtId.Text <> "" And txtReceipt.Text <> "" Then
        cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE customer Set Stu_Name = @name " & _
                                "WHERE ID = @id"
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value =  txtName.Text 
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text)
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear()
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE admin Set receipt = @recpt " & _ 
                                "WHERE ID = @id"
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@recpt", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value =  txtReceipt.Text 
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text)
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Sub
```

Not strictly related to your actual problem, but it seems pretty clear from your code that you have a global connection object and also a global command object. Don't do that. You gain very little in terms of performance but you will have problems with disposing connection, keep track of open/closed state and you will consume precious system resources. Always use a local connection object inside a using statement.