# DataReader Error VB.net and mySql

Tags: vb.net, reader

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String
    Dim md As String

    md = Me.mskmembdate.Text
    md = Me.bday.Text
    md = Me.spsbday.Text
    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()

        End If

        query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE (memor = '" & membor.Text & "')"
        sqlcom = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            Me.lblmembname.Text = reader("membname").ToString
            Me.membtype.Text = reader("membtype").ToString
            Me.mskmembdate.Text = CDate(reader("membdate")).ToString("MMddyyyy")
            Me.lname.Text = reader("lname").ToString
            Me.fname.Text = reader("fname").ToString
            Me.mname.Text = reader("mname").ToString
            Me.nameex.Text = reader("nameex").ToString
            Me.bday.Text = CDate(reader("bday")).ToString("MMddyyyy")
            Me.membtype.Text = reader("membtype").ToString
            Me.spslname.Text = reader("spslname").ToString
            Me.spsfname.Text = reader("spsfname").ToString
            Me.spsmname.Text = reader("spsmname").ToString
            Me.spsbday.Text = CDate(reader("spsbday")).ToString("MMddyyyy")
            Me.civil.Text = reader("civil").ToString
            Me.sex.Text = reader("sex").ToString
            Me.municipal.Text = reader("municipal").ToString
            Me.brgy.Text = reader("brgy").ToString
            Me.purok.Text = reader("purok").ToString
            Me.district.Text = reader("district").ToString
            Me.certno.Text = reader("certnumb").ToString
            Me.resno.Text = reader("resonumb").ToString
            Me.cpno.Text = reader("cpno").ToString
            Me.recstat.Text = reader("recstat").ToString

        End While
        reader.Close()
        conn.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "D:\N.A.C. JR\SAMPLE VB 2008\NewMembership\NewMembership\bin\Debug\profilepic.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE (memor = '" & membor.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        orspspic.Text = dr("spspicture").ToString
        orpic.Text = dr("picture").ToString
    End While
    dr.Close()
    myConnection.Close()
    varimage = orpic.Text
    varimage = orspspic.Text
    pic.ImageLocation = orpic.Text
    spspic.ImageLocation = orspspic.Text
End Sub
```

This is my code from frmload i click listview data then form2 opens and sets the data into text boxes but this error pops out "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first" ? How can i solve it . Any ideas how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: "a error about DataReader always pops out" -- don't you think the actual error description would be useful if we're to help you determine what's wrong?

Comment: thank you. i have already edited it

Comment: Can you also point out where in the code the exception is being thrown?

Comment: The error gives you a good hint at the problem, although it's not clear from the code you posted here.  You've opened a `DataReader` on a connection (presumably in Form1), then in your form2, opened another `DataReader` on the same connection without closing the first one.  It's possible that your `reader` loop is throwing an exception (thus, never closing) and you don't see it because you're not doing anything in your `Catch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse or Dispose DB Connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213871/reuse-or-dispose-db-connections)