# SELECT Query to STRING Variable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to make a form where the user inputs a SerialNb, clicks on a button, and it shows a new form, containing the remaining columns where Table.SerialNbColumn = SerialNbInput

The error I would get would be "Expression does not produce a value", I'm seriously stuck because, well, it's quite simple, but it should actually present a value.

```
Dim SQL As New SQLControl
//\\ **** USELESS CODES, ETC...

   Dim SynPayForm As New SynPaymentForm
   SynPayForm.DateFill = SQL.RunQuery("SELECT aDatePaid FROM SYNPaymentHistory WHERE SerialNb='" & SerialInput.Text & "' ")
   SynPayForm.SerialNbFill = SerialInput.Text
   SynPayForm.NameFill = SQL.RunQuery("SELECT FullName FROM SYNPaymentHistory WHERE SerialNb='" & SerialInput.Text & "' ")
   //\\ ** OTHER COLUMNS THAT HAVE SAME CONCEPT **
   SynPayForm.Show()
```

**EDIT: Added SQLControl's functions**

```
Public Class SQLControl
     Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=HOME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Project Alpha1;User=sa;Pwd=patrick442;"}
     Public SQLCmd As SqlCommand
     Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
     Public SQLDataset As DataSet

    Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

        //\\ LOAD SQL RECORDS FOR DATAGRID
        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
        SQLDataset = New DataSet
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)

        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLCon.Close()

        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably need to tell us *where* the error is an what all these mysterious methods do.  What is SQLControl?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added that in the edit. SQLControl simply contains all the basic stuff like connection, command, etc.. it just made it more clean to use that on every form, instead of all of the others.

The error would be on EVERY place where "SQL.RunQuery" is found. It always gives me an error that the result doesn't produce a value

Comment: Look at `RunQuery`.  It is a `Sub` - a void method that returns nothing.  So,  `SynPayForm.NameFill = SQL.RunQuery("...` is trying to assign the return but it doesnt return anything.  Get rid of `SQLControl` you dont need a DataAdapter and DataSet to read one column. Also learn to use SQL parameters. See also [Reuse or Dispose DB Connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452)

Comment: I actually use the RunQuery for other stuff too. I use it when adding a NEW Column, and running the query via RunQuery helps me identify if that query already exists or not (if results > 0) 

What should I modify to make it work? Can you atleast point out what I should do to fix it, if fixing the errors in a code would be too much? That'd be really appreciated