# Oracle DataReader error because already open

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I get the following error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

And this is my code so far:

```
Public Function GetPrice() As Decimal
    Dim aParams(1) As String
    Dim dPrice As Decimal

    aParams(0) = Me.ID
    aParams(1) = Me.Date

    With GetDb().GetRsWithSqlId("GET_PRICE", aParams)
        If .Read() Then
            dPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(IIf(TypeOf .Item("TS_PRICE") Is DBNull, 0.0, .Item("TS_PRICE")))
        End If
        .Close()
    End With

    Return dPrice
End Function

Public Function GetRsWithSqlId(ByVal sId As String, ByVal arrParams() As Object) As OleDbDataReader
        Dim i As Integer

        If m_oOleDbConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            If Not Connect() Then Throw New ArgumentException("Can't connect to database!" & Chr(13) & "LastError: " & LastError())
        End If

        m_oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Clear()
        m_oOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        m_oOleDbCommand.CommandText = GetSql(sId)

        If Not IsNothing(m_oOleDbTransaction) Then
            m_oOleDbCommand.Transaction = m_oOleDbTransaction
        End If

        For i = 0 To arrParams.GetLength(0) - 1
            m_oOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("?", arrParams(i)))
        Next

        Return m_oOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()

    End Function
```

The error message says that the DataReader is already in use with another command on the same connection, but I can't figure out where the reader is open.
Is there a solution to close the DataReader if it is open or to avoid using DataReader? My understanding is that without DataReader many commands can be used on the same connection at the same time or?

Comment: Any reason why you are using the OleDb provider instead of the Oracle (or even Microsoft) one specific for Oracle?

Comment: @Steve the main reason is that the whole project is using OleDb and it takes too much time to replace it everyhwere

Comment: Close and reopen the connection, the associated reader will be closed also. But this is wrong on many levels. You shouldn't have a global connection object opened for the lifetime of your application. This leads to nasty bugs and resource depletion on your machine and server. Use a local Connection object, create it, open, use it and destroy it afterwards between using blocks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There is already an open DataReader..." Reuse or Dispose DB Connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213871/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-reuse-or-dispose-db-connections)