# Database Lookup From ComboBox selection

Tags: sql, vb.net, error-handling

I have a question about database values and how to determine the id of a value that has been changed by the user at some point.

As it is currently set up there is a combobox that is populated from a dataset, and subsequent text boxes whose text should be determined by the value chosen from that combobox.

So let's say for example you select 'Company A' from the combobox, I would like all the corresponding information from that company's row in the dataset to fill the textboxes (Name = Company A, Address = 123 ABC St., etc.,)

I am able to populate the combobox just fine. It is only however when I change the index of the combobox that this specific error occurs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Here is the corresponding code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class CustomerContact

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|datadirectory|\CentralDatabase.accdb;")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Private Sub CustomerContact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Customers", cn)
        da.Fill(dt)

        Dim r As DataRow
        For Each r In dt.Rows
            cboVendorName.Items.Add(r("Name").ToString)
            cboVendorName.ValueMember = "ID"
        Next
        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboVendorName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboVendorName.SelectedIndexChanged
        cn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Customers WHERE id='" & cboVendorName.SelectedValue & "'", cn)
        da.Fill(dt)
            Dim r As DataRow
            For Each r In dt.Rows
            txtNewName.Text = "Name"
            txtAddress.Text = "Address"
            Next
            cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

The error is caught at Line 24 of this code, at the second da.Fill(dt) . Now obviously from the exception I know that I am sending in a wrong datatype into the OleDbCommand, unfortunately I am a novice when it comes to SQL commands such as this. Also please keep in mind that I can't even test the second For loop, the one that is supposed to fill the Customer information into textboxes (for convenience I only copied the first two textboxes, of which there are nine in total). I am think I could use an If statement to determine if the row has been read, and from there populate the textboxes, but I will jump that hurdle when I can reach it.

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated. Again I am a novice at managing a database and the code in question pertains to the project my current internship is having me write for them.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection, and to fix your error.

Comment: I would suggest that you dont need to run a new query at all.  That DataTable has all the customers in it already.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, I mean I see what you are saying in how the original DataTable has already been filled with the information, but then how do I determine which customer row to fill, dependent on which index of the combobox the user selected? My current thought process as you see is to run a new query with the id of the selected value from the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have all the data from that table in a `DataTable`, you dont need to run a query at all.  Setup in form load (if you must):

```vb
' form level object:
Private ignore As Boolean
Private dtCust As New DataTable
...
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Id, Name, Address, City FROM Customer"
Using dbcon = GetACEConnection()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        dtCust.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Using

' pk required for Rows.Find
ignore = True
dtCust.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtCust.Columns(0)}
cboCust.DataSource = dtCust
cboCust.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboCust.ValueMember = "Id"
ignore = False
```

The ignore flag will allow you to ignore the first change that fires as a result of the `DataSource` being set.  This will fire before the Display and Value members are set.

Preliminary issues/changes:

- Connections are meant to be created, used and disposed of.  This is slightly less true of Access, but still a good practice.  Rather than connection strings everywhere, the `GetACEConnection` method creates them for me. The code [is in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452).
- In the interest of economy, rather than a `DataAdapter` just to fill the table, I used a reader
- The `Using` statements create and dispose of the `Command` object as well.  Generally, if an object has a `Dispose` method, put it in a `Using` block.
- I spelled out the columns for the SQL.  If you don't need all the columns, dont ask for them all.  Specifying them also allows me to control the order (display order in a DGV, reference columns by index - `dr(1) = ...` - among other things).

The important thing is that rather than adding items to the cbo, I used that `DataTable` as the `DataSource` for the combo. `ValueMember` doesn't do anything without a `DataSource` - which is the core problem you had.  There was no `DataSource`, so `SelectedValue` was always `Nothing` in the event.

Then in `SelectedValueChanged` event:

```vb
Private Sub cboCust_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, 
              e As EventArgs) Handles cboCust.SelectedValueChanged

    ' ignore changes during form load:
    If ignore Then Exit Sub

    Dim custId = Convert.ToInt32(cboCust.SelectedValue)
    Dim dr = dtCust.Rows.Find(custId)

    Console.WriteLine(dr("Id"))
    Console.WriteLine(dr("Name"))
    Console.WriteLine(dr("Address"))
End Sub
```

Using the selected value, I find the related row in the `DataTable`.  Find returns that `DataRow` (or Nothing) so I can access all the other information.  Result:

> 4
>   Gautier
>   sdfsdfsdf

Another alternative would be:

```vb
Dim rows = dtCust.Select(String.Format("Id={0}", custId))
```

This would return an array of `DataRow` matching the criteria.  The `String.Format` is useful when the target column is text.  This method would not require the PK definition above:

```vb
Dim rows = dtCust.Select(String.Format("Name='{0}'", searchText))
```

For more information see:

- [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)
- [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [GetConnection() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216964/1070452)  aka `GetACEConnection`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out with this, though I have a couple of questions. First and the more obvious one, I should be able to convert the 'Console.WriteLine(dr("Name"))'  into something like txtNewName.Text = dr("Name"), correct? I wouldn't even ask that question though, if it weren't for this second one: I am getting an error that GetACEConnection is not declared. I've tried 'Using dbcon As OleDbConnection = GetACEConnection' but that does not solve that issue? I can't find any documentation online about that one either, surprisingly. Do I need another import other than OleDb?

Comment: Yes you can do `txtNewName.Text = dr("Name").ToString`  ToString is required under `Option Strict` since DataRow items are Object.  the first bullet point explains `GetAceConnection` - it is a local method to create connections so the conn string isnt flying around everywhere.  There is a link to the code for it.

Comment: Oh, sorry for missing that, I implemented the method and it works! Could I also use a Module for that bit of code, if that specific database connection is used throughout all the forms? Also, I get an InvalidCastException thrown when declaring 'custId = Conver.ToInt.......' It says I cannot cast a DataRowView into IConvertible? I should be able to make a handler for this since the program continues and does in fact work as intended after the message? Either way thanks so much for the help once again Plutonix, this is the answer to my problem!

Comment: Wait.  You might have to add an ignore flag so that the moment you set the Datasource it doesnt fire the changed event...I have updated the answer - Declare it, set it in form load and clear it, then check it in the change event to ignore the events raised during form load

Comment: I have cboVendorName.ValueMember = "ID" in the form load, and I have Dim custId = Convert.ToInt32(cboVendorName.SelectedValue) in the proper cboVendorName_selectedindexchanged sub. However this isn't an issue I think I will have any problem with myself, I just ran out of room in my last comment to thank you for helping me expand my knowledge of working with datatables today!

Comment: Yep, that ignore did it! Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: You should also perhaps check for `If dr IsNot Nothing` just to be safe when you do the look up - answers get too long if you add every single check that makes sense (like the ignore). Glad to hear it works and good luck.