# Trouble in saving a longblob image to database

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I want to get the image from the datagridview then save it to the database. Can anyone help me with this? It will be so much appreciated

Below is my code in saving the image in the database. I don't know why but it doesn't actually save anything.

```
Try
    connectionSync()
    Dim a, b As String
    Dim Sql = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (ID, IMG)values(@a,@b)"

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        a = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, ConSync)


        Dim memorystream1 As New MemoryStream()
        Dim filename As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        Dim bitmaps As New Bitmap(filename)
        bitmaps.Save(memorystream1, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim pic() As Byte = memorystream1.GetBuffer()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", bitmaps)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Next
    ConSync.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: `AddWithValue("@b", pic)`  there are several other problems, starting with it being a bad idea to save images to the DB.

Comment: @user3697824 i really don't know how to save image from datagridview to mysql. pls help me. i've been researching for this but it doesn't save on the database :(

Comment: @user3697824 i'm using an image column in the datagrid

Comment: look at your code.  look at the code in my first comment.  You create a byte array and never use it.

Comment: @user3697824 i eliminated what you've said but i still can't save the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711/3697824

Comment: @user3697824 it's using a picturebox not datagridviewimagecolumn. anyways, thank you :)

Comment: an image is an image is an image; focus on the concept not handholding.  The answer seems to cover many other things you have wrong in the code like GetBuffer

Comment: @user3697824 i thought it's different when you try to save an image from picturebox and from datagrid. because i've been using different ways (like saving from datagrid using ways of saving from picturebox) i searched on the internet and nothing is giving me what i need. anyways, thank you

Comment: @MiharuChan  Did you try debugging code with a breakpoint what is getting passed to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", bitmaps). Is it byte array or an object?