# Where to save files in a Server and make it accessible VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, client-server

I have a desktop application (VB.NET and MS Access) that work so fine and it can only be used on one computer (no shared database). I am looking at the possibility where the application can be used by 5 to 10 people at a time (Client/Server perhaps).

I decided to use MySQL for the database, which is up and running but I am still to figure where best to save images that will be uploaded by different users so that it can be accessible to all users.

**Edit:**
Should it be stored on shared folder in the server? If this is the best possible way, please how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have moved to MySQL (if you only have 5 to 10 users, I would save go to MS sql express, but you might stay with MySQL because of size restrictions) you could store the pictures in the database.

MySQL supports a BLOB data type (which is meant to store binary data).

There are some good examples of how to save and retrieve images over on codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database 
 [Store picture to database; retrieve from db into Picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624760/store-picture-as-blob-in-mysql-database-and-retrieve-from-mysql-db-directly-into)

but the basic idea is something like this (to store the data)

```
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
PbPicture.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()

FileSize = mstream.Length
Dim sqlcmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim sql As String
mstream.Close()

sql = "insert into [your table]  (picture, filename, filesize) 
                           VALUES(@File, @FileName, @FileSize)"

Try
    conn.Open()
    With sqlcmd
        .CommandText = sql
        .Connection = conn
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", FileSize)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@File", arrImage)

        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

and something like this (to get the data back from the database - PbPicture is a picturebox in this example)

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
adapter.SelectCommand = Cmd

data = New DataTable

adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("select picture from [yourtable]", conn)
commandbuild = New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter.Fill(data)

Dim lb() As Byte = data.Rows(0).Item("picture")
Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
PbPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
PbPicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
lstr.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks... The users using the system will likely be 10 maximum but they can upload up to 20, 000 files each. So, I need something viable in the long run, maybe save the file on disk and store the part in the database. The size of each file will be 10kb max.

Comment: Found out that the files where actually 5kb max