# Attempting to insert picture into sql database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, vba

I want to insert an image into my SQL database. I have this code currently and it is entering a Null where the image should be. Why is this occurring?

I'm using here a simple addquestion Class.

You can find the code I used bellow :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class addquestion
    Dim con As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=physicsapp;USER=root;PASSWORD=root;OPTION=3;")
    Dim rs As Odbc.OdbcDataReader

Private Sub addquestion_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub QuestionButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles QuestionButton.Click
    Dim myFileDlog As New OpenFileDialog


    myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = "c:/"


    myFileDlog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*" & _"|Picture Files (*.png)|*.png"


    myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 1


    myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True


    If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = _
        DialogResult.OK Then
        If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
            MsgBox("File Exists: " & _
                   myFileDlog.FileName, _
                   MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("File Not Found", _
                   MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End If


    qnametextbox.Text = myFileDlog.FileName
End Sub

    Dim ans as Char = "B"
    Dim file As String = qnametextbox.Text
    Dim question As Image
    question = Image.FromFile(file)

    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    question.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()

    Dim s As String = "INSERT INTO tests VALUES (@Question ,'" & ans & "', 200)"

    Dim sql As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(s, con)
    sql.Parameters.Add("@Question", Odbc.OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = data
    con.Open()
    sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

this is the definition of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `tests` (
  `Question` blob NOT NULL,
  `CorrectAnswer` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QuestionNumber` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  KEY `QuestionNumber` (`QuestionNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Any suggestion can help.

Thanks.

Comment: 1-Which DBMS you are working on? From your connection it looks like MYSQL. Remove sql-server tag from question.

Comment: 2-Post SQL definition of table you are inserting into.

Comment: where do you define `ans`

Comment: @Nomeaning25 ans is just char thats set through radio buttons

Comment: @PatrikTřeštík  Not sure if this is what you're after, CREATE TABLE tests (  Question blob NOT NULL,  CorrectAnswer varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL, QuestionNumber int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, KEY QuestionNumber (QuestionNumber) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Are you sure that 'data' is not empty? Try replacing type with ' Odbc.OdbcType.Image'.

Comment: @PatrikTřeštík I changed data to this, however I still get the same result. When I look at the "data" variable it isnt empty either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711/1070452

Comment: The MySq; data providers would be better to use than ODBC, since there are more 2 columns in the table, you should specify which columns you are inserting into

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what data access technology or database you use, you need to convert am `Image` to a `Byte` first and then save that. On retrieval, you convert the `Byte` array back to an `Image`.

To save:

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Picture = @Picture WHERE ID = 1", connection)

'Create an Image object.'
Using picture As Image = Image.FromFile("file path here")
    'Create an empty stream in memory.'
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
        'Fill the stream with the binary data from the Image.'
        picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        'Get an array of Bytes from the stream and assign to the parameter.'
        command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.GetBuffer()
    End Using
End Using

connection.Open()
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
```

Comment: I dont see the difference between this code and my original code, but I updated my code to match yours and get the same error at the command.ExecuteNonQuery line saying: "ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.33]Column 'Question' cannot be null"

Comment: myabe you should if possible try changing data type to longblob

Comment: Image im trying to add is only 8kb but doesnt work when I change it to Longblob anyway

Comment: try this link there is vb.net solution which uses binaryreader  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-BLOB-Images-from-MySql-Database-in-ASPNet-C-and-VBNet.aspx