# how to update picture in mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have tried this code here to insert and show picture from database to picturebox : stackoverflow.com/questions/5624760/store-picture-to-database-retrieve-from-db-into-picturebox

and yeah, it is working , but when i tried to do update using the same syntax as insert it got this error :

[image]

this is the insert syntax i use :

```
Dim FileSize As UInt32
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
gambar.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)  
Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()

FileSize = mstream.Length

mstream.Close()

call konek
strSQL = "insert into tbmahasiswa VALUES ('" & _
                    txtNIM.Text & "','" & _
                    txtNama.Text & "','" & _
                    Format(dtpTanggal.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & _
                    txtAlamat.Text & "','" & _
                    cboJurusan.Text & "',@gambar)"
com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

With com
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@gambar", arrImage)
  .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

and this the code i use to show picture from database to picture box :

```
Dim imgData As Byte()

call konek
strSQL = "select * from tbMahasiswa where NIM ='" & txtNIM.Text & "'"
com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
Using rd = com.ExecuteReader

  rd.Read()
  If rd.HasRows Then
            txtNama.Text = rd.Item(1)
            dtpTanggal.Value = rd.Item(2)
            txtAlamat.Text = rd.Item(3)

            imgData = TryCast(rd.Item(5), Byte())

            If imgData IsNot Nothing Then

                Using ms As New MemoryStream(imgData)

                    gambar.Image = CType(Image.FromStream(ms), Image)

                End Using
            End If

        End If

    End Using
```

Both Insert and Retrieving Picture Code above is Working ! , and then i use this code for update :

```
Dim FileSize As UInt32
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
gambar.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)  
Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()

FileSize = mstream.Length

mstream.Close()

call konek
strSQL = "update tbmahasiswa set Nama ='" & txtNama.Text & _
                     "', TglLahir ='" & Format(dtpTanggal.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & _
                     "', Alamat ='" & txtAlamat.Text & _
                     "', Jurusan ='" & cboJurusan.Text & _
                     "', gambar =' @gambar" & _
                     "' where NIM ='" & txtNIM.Text & "'"
            com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

With com
  .Parameters.AddWithValue("@gambar", arrImage)
  .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

and then i got the error like in the picture above, all other data is correctly saved except the picture, it become some unknown file blob 8 KB size.

i'm still newbie at insert , update, delete picture in VB, please can you tell me what is wrong with the Update syntax code , is it already true but i'm missing something ? or is it totally wrong with the syntax ? please i need your guide here...

UPDATE :
actually there is "call konek" above "STRSQL" in the code, "konek" have the code for open the mysql connection,i put it in the separate module, here the full code in my module :

```
Module modKoneksi

Public conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
Public rd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
Public com As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

Public strSQL As String

Public Sub konek()
    conn.Close()
    strSQL = "server='localhost';user='root';pwd='';database='dbsekolah';"
    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = strSQL
        conn.Open()

    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

hope this makes you easier to solve my problem

Comment: Um, your code is nothing like that of the question or answer and ignores the issues described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711/1070452)

Comment: You also have single quotes around the parameter @gambar.   You may be better off changing all of the inserts and updates to use parameters to avoid the usual SQL injection attacks. A data access library like Dapper may help remove the need for all the boiler plate code around configuring parameters.

Comment: i see, actually i'm still don't know left or right with this issues. if it not troublesome for you can you create new vb project for insert,update and retrieve it to picturebox then upload it. i know it just take a few minutes for you. well if its too troublesome , can you explain more detailly where and what's wrong in the code i use ? thanks

Comment: You *have* the answer(s) in the link you posted.  SQL Parameters are not a stylistic choice - they make working with DBs simple and data type conversions very unlikely.

Comment: and yeah it is works for insert and retrieving data to picture box, but when i tried to do update its got error. can you explain that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its late but this is the working code for me :

**For retrieving the record from database with pictures :**

```
    Call konek() 'Call the connection module'
    strSQL = "select * from tbMahasiswa where ID ='" & txtID.Text & "'"
    com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
    Using rd = com.ExecuteReader

        rd.Read()
        If rd.HasRows Then
            txtNIM.Text = rd.Item(1)
            txtNama.Text = rd.Item(2)
            dtpTanggal.Value = rd.Item(3)
            txtAlamat.Text = rd.Item(4)


            imgData = TryCast(rd.Item(6), Byte())

            If imgData IsNot Nothing Then


                Using ms As New MemoryStream(imgData)

                    gambar.Image = CType(Image.FromStream(ms), Image)

                End Using
            End If
            cboJurusan.SelectedIndex = cboJurusan.FindStringExact(rd.Item(5))
        End If

    End Using
```

**For inserting record to database with pictures :**

```
Call konek()

strSQL = "Insert Into tbmahasiswa Values ('" & txtID.Text & _
    "','" & txtNIM.Text & _
    "','" & txtNama.Text & _
    "','" & Format(dtpTanggal.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & _
    "','" & txtAlamat.Text & _
    "','" & cboJurusan.Text & _
    "',@gambar)"
com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

With com
    If opdGambar.FileName = Nothing Then 'opdGambar is a PictureBox name'
        .Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@gambar", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.LongBlob)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("man-icon.png") 'Insert field gambar using an existing file in debug folder if file does not exist in PictureBox'
    Else
        .Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@gambar", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.LongBlob)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(opdGambar.FileName) 'Insert field gambar using an existing file in PictureBox'
    End If

    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

**For updating record to database with pictures :**

```
Call konek()
Dim adapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("select gambar from tbmahasiswa where ID='" & txtID.Text & "'", conn)

Dim dt As New DataTable("gambar")
adapter.Fill(dt)

strSQL = "update tbmahasiswa set NIM='" & txtNIM.Text & _
         "',Nama='" & txtNama.Text & _
         "',TglLahir='" & Format(dtpTanggal.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & _
         "',Alamat='" & txtAlamat.Text & _
         "',Jurusan='" & cboJurusan.Text & _
         "' ,Gambar=@gambar where id='" & txtID.Text & "'"
com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

With com

    If opdGambar.FileName = Nothing Then 
        Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(row(0), Byte()))
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
            gambar.Image = img

            .Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@gambar", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.LongBlob)).Value = (CType(row(0), Byte())) 'field gambar will use the current existing file in database if PictureBox does not have a file'

        End Using
    Else
        .Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@gambar", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.LongBlob)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(opdGambar.FileName) 
    End If

    com.ExecuteNonQuery()

End With
```

i hope for those who find the other answer a little confusing (like me), will find this answer helpful.