# Inserting a PNG or JPG into MySQL is corrupting the image

Tags: mysql, vb.net, png, jpeg, corrupt

I have a problem with inserting some JPG or PNG images into MySQL. Some of these images are corrupt.

Screenshot of corrupt JPG:

[image: JPG Corrupt]

Screenshot of corrupt PNG:

[image: PNG Corrupt]

What is wrong with my code?

Code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim FileSize As UInt32
    Dim rawData() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Try
        fs = New FileStream(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        FileSize = fs.Length
        rawData = New Byte(FileSize) {}
        fs.Read(rawData, 0, FileSize)
        'fs.Close()
        MysqlConn.Open()
        SQL = "INSERT INTO xcollectibles.foto (foto) VALUES(@foto)"
        cmd.Connection = MysqlConn
        cmd.CommandText = SQL
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", rawData)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        fs.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("File Inserted into database successfully!",
        "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error: " & ex.Message, "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MysqlConn.Open()
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim filesize As UInt32
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        If TextBox1.Text = ".jpg" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".png" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".bmp" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

        End If


        'Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        'Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        'g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
        'bmp.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)


        'End If
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
        filesize = mstream.Length
        mstream.Close()
        SQL = "INSERT INTO xcollectibles.foto (id_product,foto) VALUES ((Select id from xcollectibles.product where product.name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'), @foto) "
        ProgressBar1.Value = i
        cmd.Connection = MysqlConn
        cmd.CommandText = SQL
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", arrImage)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("File Inserted into database successfully!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

---

I try something different now....
Save the file in a path of the computer and save the path in mysql

I try this to add the file

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images" & "\" & ComboBox1.Text)
        Dim SaveFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images" & "\" & ComboBox1.Text & "\" & TextBox3.Text)

        If TextBox1.Text = ".jpg" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images\mypic.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".bmp" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images\mypic.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".png" Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images\mypic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        End If
```

But i want saving the file with the folder of

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images" & "\" & ComboBox1.Text)
```

and save the file with the name of TextBox3.Text

```
Dim SaveFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images" & "\" & ComboBox1.Text & "\" & TextBox3.Text)
```

Because with in the exemple of

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\Users\Jamyz\Source\Repos\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\xCollectibles\Images\mypic.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The file is overwrites ........

Thank you so much.......

Comment: _“What is wrong with my code ???”_ – besides the fact that you are trying to put images into the database in the first place, you mean? Images belong into the file system, not a database.

Comment: @CBroe: This is not correct and not very helpful at all. It may be a rule of thumb one should keep in mind when designing a new application though.

Comment: I think the problem is quite straightforward. You shouldn't use images in database! Specially your images look to be of high resolution and thus it gets corrupted because you probably can't save all the bytes to your database. Try with an icon 16*16px and you'll see it probably works.

Comment: Storing image data rather than the filename will needlessly bloat the DB.  However, use SQL PArameters always, use Add rather than AddWithValue and `GetBuffer` is wrong.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store picture to database; retrieve from db into Picturebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624760/store-picture-to-database-retrieve-from-db-into-picturebox) - see the [answer by Plutonix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the image to a byte array before you can store it in a database.  I use Oracle, but I imagine that Sql Server is the same.  I capture the photo from a upload, scale the image to a thumbnail and then convert it to a byte array to store in the database.  See code below:

```
    If Not file1.PostedFile Is Nothing And file1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
        Session("ThePhoto") = ""
        Dim TheStream As Stream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream
        Dim origimage As System.Drawing.Image
        origimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(TheStream)

        Dim ms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        origimage = ScaleImage(origimage, 320, 200) ' Thumbnail
        origimage.Save(ms2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Dim MyPhoto() As Byte = ms2.GetBuffer ' The scaled image is now stored in memory as a byte array
        Session("ThePhoto") = MyPhoto ' put it into the session to retreive later
        ms2.Dispose()
        origimage.Dispose()
    End If
```

I store the image in the session object because there are other things going on and I can't yet save the image to the database until the user clicks the save button.  It's pretty straight forward to pass the byte array to a stored procedure to save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help i use that. The probleme is solve

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim SQL As String
        'Dim FileSize As UInt32
        Dim rawData() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ListBox1.SelectedItem)


        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
        mstream.Close()

        'Save Image in Folder
        Dim strBasePath As String
        Dim strFileName As String
        strFileName = TextBox3.Text
        strBasePath = Application.StartupPath & "\Images" & ComboBox1.Text & "\"
        ' >> Check if Folder Exists 
        If Directory.Exists(strBasePath) = False Then
                Call Directory.CreateDirectory(strBasePath)
            End If
        ' >> Save Picture 
        If TextBox1.Text = ".jpg" Then
            Call PictureBox1.Image.Save(strBasePath & "\" & strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".png" Then
            Call PictureBox1.Image.Save(strBasePath & "\" & strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = ".bmp" Then
            Call PictureBox1.Image.Save(strBasePath & "\" & strFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If
        'Save Image in Folder

        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Open()
        SQL = "INSERT INTO xcollectibles.foto (id_product,name,path) VALUES ((Select id from xcollectibles.product where product.name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'), @name, @path) "
        ProgressBar1.Value = i
        cmd.Connection = MysqlConn
        cmd.CommandText = SQL
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", strBasePath)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("File Inserted into database successfully!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```