# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when update

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

When I update a form I have this error only when I don't update(change) the image.
When I update with a new image I don't have this error.

```
Try
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(mstream))
    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
    mstream.Close()

    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn
    COMMAND.CommandText = "update product set 
        id_maker=@Value1, 
        foto=@foto  
        where id = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox1.Text), DBNull.Value, ComboBox1.Text))

    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foto", arrImage)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados")
    MysqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
MysqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: I don't understand how your code works at all. In the first line you are initialising a new MemoryStream that isn't given any parameters, and then immediately afterwards you are trying to get an image from it?  Also please identify the exact line of code that is causing the exception and please post the full exception details.

Comment: What do you mean `when i dont update(change) the image` your code shows image data being passed no matter what.  There is plenty wrong with the code in addition to the above a) do not use `GetBuffer()`, use `ToArray` - consider no saving an image at all, but the name of a file saved to some archive location; b) do not use `AddWithValue()` use the `Add(string, dbType).Value = ...` form c) always use SQL parameters including the WHERE clause target d) ExecuteNonQuery would be better than a DataReader

Comment: @DeanOC unfortunately with that error, `A generic error...` *is* the details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I Try this and work.

```
Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                'PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(mstream))
                PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
```

Comment: do not use `GetBuffer()`, use `ToArray()` the drawbacks are clearly outlined on MSDN...[and here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711)